# Using "override" specifier

Tags: c++11

ALL,

In my program I'm using a library which uses macros.

One of the macros is using virtual function.

Now every time I'm making a child of the class I'm getting an error about missing `override`, since I'm building in C++11+.

Is there an easy way to fix such a warning without changing the library code significantly?

Or I'm out of luck and have to bite the bullet and replace all macro instances with the full implementation?

Thank you.

Comment: As `override` is not required, you should be able to disable that warning. But this is compiler specific... However, better to take good habit and use `override` specifier so that compiler would case unintended mistach while override a function. **However, you should not have to modify a library you didn't wrote**.

Comment: @Phil1970, yes, it is not required as its just a warning. But it just pollutes the build log and something important might slip up under the radar. It is a good habit, but when I use the class derived from the one that has the macro, I'm getting this warning. And the warning is generated inside that library whenever this class is used as a parent for other classes. So as I stated in the OP - I can either modify the library and ask the author for an approval (if they are alive and reachable in this times) or just live with the warning.

Comment: If you have only one macro that is problematic, you might simply decide to rewrite your version of it that is exactly as the original one plus the `override` specifier. But without any example or details, it is hard to give specific help.